# User with read permissions cannot share file\folder with site collection administrator but can share with another regular users

Tags: sharepoint-online

Regular user has read permissions to the folder. User can share this folder with another regular users but faced error when trying to share folder with site collection administrator.

Error - **The recipient you entered doesn't have permission to access the item**.

If we grant site collection admin role to regular user the problem will go away. But we cannot go by this way.

See image. Regular user trying to share folder with site collection administrator.
[image]

Lockdown limited access feature is deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we've requested support from MS. MS confirmed that this issue is by design and advise us to add an idea on SharePoint Community site.

We created an [idea](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/cce6c945-1236-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93) on community site.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting bug. I can reproduce it in my tenant. My guess is that the read only user has permission to see the permissions of other users, but wouldn't have access to know who site collection admins are.

The workaround would be to add the site collection administrator as an Owner (as well as being a site collection admin).

Regular read only user could remain as read only user.

Comment: Adding site collection administrator as an Owner did not help due to this folder is restricted area and has unique permissions. Site owners group doesn't have access to this folder.

Comment: Oh I see. Then I guess you are stuck because a read only user can't change the permissions, they can only send a link to a user that already has permissions.

Comment: But SharePoint Site coll admins has permissions ) It is a bug

Comment: I guess it's not a bug if a read only user doesn't have permission to find out who the site collection admins are

Comment: From user perspective - user receives message - The recipient you entered doesn't have permission to access the item. But actually recipient(site collection admin) has access. For my point of view - it is not correct.